# How can I prevent nginx from buffering within PHP?

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to push a page to the browser while it is being generated from a PHP script. I have no access to my hosting provider's nginx configuration but they have told me that they use nginx 1.8.1. In my `phpinfo()` output I can see

```
output_buffering    0   0
```

and the same script works as expected on my local PC.

This is my starting script:

```
<pre>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
  print('<b>.</b>');
  flush();
  usleep(100000); // 0.1 second
}
?>
</pre>
```

I start getting output immediately on my local PC but I have to wait the full 10 seconds before I see anything when the page is accessed from my hosting.

---

These are the default response headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 12:32:05 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
>   **Content-Encoding: gzip**

---

If I add

```
<?php
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

I get

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 12:35:10 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
>   Content-Encoding: gzip

---

```
<?php
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
header('Content-Encoding: identity');
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 12:37:11 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   **Content-Length: 812**
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
>   Content-Encoding: identity

Obviously, if the server knows the length of the content, it has waited for the script to finish before starting to send it to the browser.

These are the headers on my local machine:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 12:52:31 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.4.45 OpenSSL/1.0.1e
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
>   X-Accel-Buffering: no
>   Content-Encoding: identity
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

The `X-Accel-Buffering` header gets passed through because I am not running nginx locally.

Are there any other headers I can pass through from PHP to stop nginx from buffering the content? So far I've only found config options, which I don't have access to.

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip` is probably the issue; if nginx compresses the response it necessarily needs to buffer it for a bit. The best question to ask would be how to signal to nginx to forgo compression.

Comment: @deceze That's what `header('Content-Encoding: identity');` is for; it forces nginx to not gzip the content which you can see worked, even though it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have `fastcgi_ignore_headers` directive?

Comment: Ah, right, ignore me.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Is that a PHP thing or an nginx thing and how can I check?

Comment: It's a nginx's directive. Check in nginx's config

Comment: @AlexeyTen I have absolutely no access to the nginx config, not even read-only.

Comment: If you don't have access to nginx's config, then you cannot do anything. Ask your system administrator